# AS3 and the microphone class

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, microphone

In Java there is a method of the AudioFormat called

```
getSampleRate
```

This returns the number of samples per second.

I was wondering what the best way to achieve this with the microphone in flash is. I am not sure if I need to add a SamplesDatatEvent and use extract() or ??

I need to know the number of samples per second from the audio coming into the mic.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions in 1 here. "And using extract()", that is a totally separate issue from getting and setting the sample rate in flash, and I would argue that working with the SampleDataEvent is separate from getting and setting the sample rate. This to me is 3 questions in 1. Can you either split this into pointed questions or make a more elaborate question?

Comment: Sorry I will try to update to a better question.

Comment: Np :) The main confusion comes in with the last line "And using extract()" Need more detail. :)

Comment: Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microphone class has a 'rate' getter/setter:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#rate

Seems to default to either 8kHz or 11kHz, settable up to 44kHz (44.1, I assume).

You can add a 'SampleDataEvent' listener to get access to the bytes.